# Python overriding setter to an attribute with no setter?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, properties, getter-setter

I have a class `A` made by someone else, that I cannot edit:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
```

Now I'm trying to inherit my own class `B` from `A`, and have `x` as a property instead of an attribute.
Is this possible?

I already tried:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super().__init__(x)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return super().x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        super().x = x
        print(x)  # my stuff goes here
```

But as I expected, it's not possible: `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'x'`

Is there any other method, some workaroud maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use `super()` for anything other than class attributes; `x` is an *instance* attribute, and there is no inheritance mechanism for attributes.

Instance attributes live in a single namespace; there is no 'parent instance' attribute namespace.

You can still reach the attribute in the instance `__dict__` object:

```
class B(A):
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__dict__['x']

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self.__dict__['x'] = x
        print(x)  # my stuff goes here
```

A property is a *data descriptor*, meaning that it is looked up before the instance attributes are consulted (see the [descriptor howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)), but you can still access it directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll accept asap. :) Might be a bit "hacky" way (well, at least looks a bit hacky to access `__dict__`), but seems to work just great